# Can Azure Website scale across multiple availability zones

Tags: azure

We currently have a standard website running in Azure Websites within the West Europe region across 2 different instances. My question is, can these be scaled across multiple availability zones i.e. West Europe and North Europe? We had an hour outage in this zone this morning and the site was down for that duration which the client is not happy about.

Is this possible? And on that note, can the same be done for SQL Azure database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Traffic Manager now supports Azure Websites.  In a nutshell, Traffic Manager is a data center load balancer.

Check the announcement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/27/azure-traffic-manager-can-now-integrate-with-azure-web-sites.aspx

Comment: This would require setting up 2 separate websites in 2 different regions, correct? There would need to be some form of file replication  service running as your websites would not be pointing to the same drive. Is this assumption correct or is this possible?

Comment: Exact.  The challenge is to keep the deployments in sync.  Another option is to use Traffic Manager to fallback to a read only version of your site.

Comment: Biggest challenge with TM is keeping data in sync across the data centers